# Borderless window in clutter(mm)

Tags: c++, clutter

I'm trying to use cluttermm to create a borderless window (for example, something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aGNOME_Do_Classic.png)).

In other words, I want to draw a rectangle on screen and some text on it, but NOT in a window, and NOT with borders.

Is clutter a really bad choice for this, or how can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clutter itself doesn't offer any API to do this, and defers to the platform's API to control the actual window.

you can use Clutter-GTK and the GtkWindow API to remove the decoration from the window embedding the stage.

Comment: I just noticed I never replied to this nor marked this answer as accepted, sorry about that.  That's all I needed to know, thanks :)